# Asking for location permissions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an action that is requesting location, but I'm a little confused by the Dialogflow setup of this. This is my code:

```
app.intent('bus_stop_nearby_permission', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new Permission({
    context: 'To get nearby bus stops',
    permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION',
  }));
});

app.intent('bus_stop_nearby', (conv, input, granted) => {
  if (granted) {
    conv.close(`Location was granted ${JSON.stringify(conv)}`);
  } else {
    conv.close(`Location was not granted!`);
  }
});
```

In Dialogflow the initial intent `bus_stop_nearby_permission` is triggered by asking for bus stops near me with a training phrase, there is *no* event attached to this dialog. The follow-up intent `bus_stop_nearby` has the `action_intent_PERMISSION` event attached to it and no training phrases. Right now my action asks for permissions but doesn't understand any confirmation input, and just defers to the fallback intent when I say yes to it.

**Screenshots of bus_stop_nearby intent:**

[image: bus_stop_nearby intent]

**Screenshot of bus_stop_nearby_permission:**

[image]

Do I need to add follow up contexts for when the user approves the location request?

Comment: Please update your question to include a screen shot of the "bus_stop_nearby" Intent.

Comment: I've updated the main post with the screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event should be `actions_intent_PERMISSION` with an "s" at the end of "action".

Easy and common typo to miss.